# Como incluir valor excedente no resultado de uma consulta com LIMIT SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Olá,

Possuo uma tabela de IDH mundial e gostaria de efetuar uma consulta dos 10 países com maior IDH e mas incluir nessa consulta o Brasil (que não está entre os 10 maiores). Como resultado, seriam 11 países.
De que forma posso fazer essa consulta? É possível adicionar a posição no ranking (por exemplo: 1, Níger;
2, República Centro-Africana; 3, Eritreia...)

A minha consulta inicial está da seguinte forma (sem incluir o Brasil):

```
SELECT pais, ano, valor
  FROM  idh
  ORDER BY valor
  LIMIT 10;
```

Utilizo PostgreSQL 13.1.

Comment: Tem pergunta disso já no site, vou ver se localizo o link. basta fazer `order by pais != "Brasil", valor` ou um UNION de 2 selects, um com WHERE pais="BRASIL" e outro com a query atual (pegando 9, por exemplo)

Comment: Não lembrei de utilizar o UNION e funcionou certinho. Obrigadão.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso é usando union.

```
SELECT pais, ano, valor
    FROM  idh
   ORDER BY valor
   LIMIT 10
 union
SELECT pais, ano, valor
    FROM  idh
 where pais = 'BRASIL'
```